# Re-load Unloaded Projects in EnvDTE

Tags: c#, projects-and-solutions, envdte

I have listed all the projects in my solution, using EnvDTE, but I found a bug in my code: I can't get the projects that are Unloaded.

I found a way to skip the Unloaded projects:

```
if (string.Compare(EnvDTE.Constants.vsProjectKindUnmodeled, project.Kind, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
  continue;
```

This way, my code doesn't crash - but I am unable to load the missing projects through code, since they exist already.

How can I Load the Unloaded projects into the solution ?

I have tried:

```
project.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Project.ReloadProject");
```

And got error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (...): Command "Project.ReloadProject" is not available.

So I tried to somehow get

```
application.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Project.ReloadProject");
```

But before that, from every place I searched on the NET, I must pre-select the project in the solution - and for that, I need `project.Name` (which I have), and the path, which I don't (every example I have found assumes that the solution path is the same as the project path, which is highly unlikely in a generic situation).

Comment: What's type (full namespace) is `application` ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._dte.application.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Visual Studio SDK is apparently the way to do this.

```
var dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE");
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIHierarchyWindow hierarchy;
ServiceProvider sp = new ServiceProvider((Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)dte);
IVsSolution sol = (IVsSolution)sp.GetService(typeof(SVsSolution));

foreach (ProjInfo info in GetProjectInfo(sol))
{
    info.Dump();

}
//from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/60fdd7b4-2247-4c18-b1da-301390edabf3/
static IEnumerable<ProjInfo> GetProjectInfo(IVsSolution sol)
{
  Guid ignored = Guid.Empty;
  IEnumHierarchies hierEnum;
  if (ErrorHandler.Failed(sol.GetProjectEnum((int)__VSENUMPROJFLAGS.EPF_ALLPROJECTS, ref ignored, out hierEnum)))
  {
    yield break;
  }

  IVsHierarchy[] hier = new IVsHierarchy[1];
  uint fetched;
  while ((hierEnum.Next((uint)hier.Length, hier, out fetched) == VSConstants.S_OK) && (fetched == hier.Length))
  {
    int res = (int)VSConstants.S_OK;

    Guid projGuid;
    if (ErrorHandler.Failed(res = sol.GetGuidOfProject(hier[0], out projGuid)))
    {
        Debug.Fail(String.Format("IVsolution::GetGuidOfProject returned 0x{0:X}.", res));
        continue;
    }

    string uniqueName;
    if (ErrorHandler.Failed(res = sol.GetUniqueNameOfProject(hier[0], out uniqueName)))
    {
        Debug.Fail(String.Format("IVsolution::GetUniqueNameOfProject returned 0x{0:X}.", res));
        continue;
    }
    if( System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars().Any (p =>uniqueName.Contains(p) ))
    {
        uniqueName.Dump("invalid filename found");
        yield return new ProjInfo(projGuid,uniqueName);
    } 
    else {
        yield return new ProjInfo(projGuid, Path.GetFileName(uniqueName).BeforeOrSelf("{"));
    }
  }
}
```

got most of it from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/60fdd7b4-2247-4c18-b1da-301390edabf3/

Comment: What is **Info.Dump()** ?

Comment: Comes from LinqPad it's kinda like `Console.WriteLine` on steroids.